# Parts of speech conundrum

Tags: parts-of-speech

> He studied all day long.

He -> Pronoun

studied -> verb (in past tense)

all -> ??

day -> noun ?

long -> adverb ?

I would like to know the part of speech that all is in this sentence. My train of thought: (all day) is a noun in combination. So all might be an adjective ?

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, *all* is a **predeterminer**, which gives more information about the noun in a noun phrase (all day).

See definition **A1** given by the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all)

> Every one (of), or the complete amount or number (of), or the whole (of)
>   - *He studied **the whole of** the day long.*